# Real analysis: Limit of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Question: 
If $0<a<b$ determine the limit $\left(\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n} \right)$

Attempt:
Well we cannot assume that any of them are convergent on their own as they could be greater then 1 and so they could all diverge individualy. I was thinking if I could show 
$\lim \left(\frac{a^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}\right)$ is convergent then the same with $b^{n+1}$ then their sum is convergent. I can only use simple theorems, no derivative.

Comment: limit as what goes where?  In your attempt it sounds like a sum.  Sum of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another more direct (imo) approach using that $\;x^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ whenever $\;|x|<1\;$ :

$$\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}=\frac{b^{n+1}\left(\left(\frac ab\right)^{n+1}+1\right)}{b^n\left(\left(\frac ab\right)^n+1\right)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}b\frac{0+1}{0+1}=b$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=bk$, where $k \in (0,1)$. We then get
$$\dfrac{a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n} = \dfrac{b^{n+1}k^{n+1} + b^{n+1}}{b^nk^n+b^n} = b \left(\dfrac{1+k^{n+1}}{1+k^n}\right)$$
What happens to $k^n$ and $k^{n+1}$ as $n \to \infty$, if $k \in (0,1)$?

Comment: They obviously will approach 0. So you end up with the whole express =b which shows its convergent. Thank you sir!